# Final Verdict. Are build reviews (Not requests) on topic?

Tags: discussion

[This question touches the subject](https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/464/are-build-requests-on-topic) but asking for a review of a suggested build, is it on topic here? [This question](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/6935/modest-home-office-desktop-pc-build) was placed on hold. It's not necessarily a low quality question, its just on the rim of on/off topic.

I love Hardware, and if this question was to ask about any one of these components individually, (This is my build, is this PSU good enought?) I'm sure it would fall into the on-topic realm. But when asking about an entire build, I can see a lot of repetitive answers.... Tons of PCpartpicker links, and amd/intel/nvidia fan boys pushing their latest release. Not that this stack is filled with fanboys, but eventually it could become a red/green pissing match that I think we all want to avoid.

On the other side, these questions are fun to answer and could generate more page activity. Maybe a trail run? I don't know, still working on my caffeine for the day.

What was the final verdict for these types of questions? Has one been made? If not, lets rap.

Answer (score 1):

Build reviews are not good questions here. They are overly broad and often fall into two categories, which the edit to your linked question summarizes nicely:

> I have two questions:
>
> - Will these components be compatible?
> - Is this system good value-for money? For example, have I over-specced or under-specced in any specific area?

---

#### Will these be compatible

Unless someone is going completely off the rails with their hardware, the answer is "Yes, to a degree" for almost everything. If someone can put together a build list, they've likely done enough research to know if the motherboard will support their RAM or CPU.

#### Is this a good value

That's entirely up to the user to decide. What I value in my hardware is different than what my siblings value in theirs and is probably different than what you value in yours. I'll gladly spend more money on some components and not others based on my experiences building machines and using them for different purposes.

---

The third category, which the example question didn't fall into, is: Build my machine for me. I have these X components already. What else do I need?

These are too broad.

---

I like the one component per question guidance that we have already. This allows us to focus on a single part. If the user provides additional components that are in the machine (or links to other questions), that helps us provide better input but still focus on a single component per question.

Comment: Well, We have some mods that close build requests on sight using the "technical support" reason, and other mods that leave them be.   Is consistency too much to ask?

Comment: I think a "build request" close reason might be a good thing, but I haven't looked at our close statistics recently to see if it's actually needed.

Comment: See the meta question I posted, as it could be another way to handle build requests, as they really belong on Super User.

Comment: @NZKshatriya That was the underlying reason for this question.Establish what the standard is and how build reviews should be handled moving forward. I agree with you about these questions might be better placed somewhere else.